# Regex Keep variable text

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Ok so I've been searching for hours on how to do this:

A user adds the following text to the box and clicks convert

> 1 127.0.0.1:8080 Some random junk over here 127.0.0.1
>   2 255.255.255.255:80 random junk is different every line www.example.com
>   3 98.76.54.32:1010 blah blah blah 98.76.54.32

Using this code:

```
outputBox.Text = Regex.Replace(inputBox.Text, "^[[0-9]{1,3},[.],[0-9]{1,3},[.],[0-9]{1,3},[.],[0-9]{1,3},[:],[0-9]{1,5}]+", "");
```

it should turn into this:

> 127.0.0.1:8080
>   255.255.255.255:80
>   98.76.54.32:1010

But instead the output box displays the exact same thing as what was inputted

The only thing that all of the desired text has in common is that it is
1-3 digits followed a period (x3) Then 1-3 digits followed by a colon followed by 1-5 digits

I also tried many variants of the code (removing commas, removing brackets around the periods, etc.) None of which work

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think your usage of replace method is not correct. Have u given any pattern to the Regex. First study the use of replace in the following link..............  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why replace with `""` dont make any sense, a better logic can be capture the `IP:port` as `Regex Group` and then replace the match with first group `$1`

```
outputBox.Text = Regex.Replace(inputBox.Text, @"\d+ ((?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}:\d{1,5}).+", "$1\r\n")
```

Comment: Don't you need to escape the colon as well?

Comment: @RichardBrown - nope, it is not a Special Regex character, you can Verify it using `Regex.Escape(":"); // prints -> :`

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! But your method removes line breaks in between attempts ie. 127.0.0.1:8080255.255.255.255:8098.76.54.32:1010

Comment: @Kazankoph -  well then change the replace part with `"$1\r\n"`

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

```
        string haystack = "127.0.0.1:8080 this is some ip and port 127.0.0.1";
        Regex needle = new Regex("[0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}([:][0-9]{2,5})?");

        string output = String.Empty;
        string[] lines = haystack.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            if (needle.IsMatch(line))
            {
                output += needle.Match(line).ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
            }
        }
        // output 127.0.0.1:8080
```